# Trouble understanding how tuple recursion works in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, tuples

I am having trouble understanding how this function works. The function is supposed to take in a string and split that string into a pair, of which the first element is the first 'word' that is in the string and the second element is the remainder of the input string.

In particular, on line 6, I understand why the function should terminate when `isSpace c` is true but don't understand why that should return a tuple with the first element being the empty list. I was wondering if someone could explain why this works with a relatively simple (but non-trivial) example such as `nextWord "an apple"`.

```
import Data.Char
nextWord :: String -> (String, String)
nextWord []
  = ([],[])
nextWord (c:cs)
  | isSpace c = ([], cs)
  | otherwise = (c: word, other)
  where
    (word, other) = nextWord cs
```

EDIT: As an example of what this function returns when the given argument starts with a space, nextWord " hello" should return ("", "hello").

Comment: "why that should return a tuple with the first element being the empty list". What should it return instead?

Comment: Can you write that value down in Haskell?

Comment: This is not tuple recursion. It is a recursive function returning a tuple. In the space case it returns the empty list as the first component: this is actually the empty string. This is done so that the recursive call can add the characters in front of that so to isolate the first word in the input string.

Comment: @Jubobs I paraphrased the problem. This was just one function in an entire pdf of functions to practise Haskell. The spec however did not mention the case when the argument starts off with the space so it was ambiguous. However, after finding the solution and using that function , it seems to "ignore" that case, so nextWord " hello" returns ("", "hello"). My question was that I don't understand how the terminating case (line 6) builds up the word character by character and returns the correct tuple when it appears to return a tuple in which first element is [] and second element is cs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's step through it!

```
nextWord "an apple"
```

Since `"an apple"` doesn't pattern match against `[]`, we're in the second case. Substituting in `'a': "n apple"` for `c : cs`, we get:

```
nextWord ('a':"n apple")
  | isSpace 'a' = ([], "n apple")
  | otherwise = ('a': word, other)
  where
    (word, other) = nextWord "n apple"
```

`isSpace 'a'` is `False`, so this simplifies to

```
nextWord ('a':"n apple") = ('a': word, other)
  where (word, other) = nextWord "n apple"
```

Similarly, for `nextWord "n apple"` we get

```
nextWord ('n':" apple") = ('n': word, other)
  where (word, other) = nextWord " apple"
```

And for `nextWord " apple"` we get

```
nextWord (' ':"apple")
  | isSpace ' ' = ([], "apple")
  | otherwise = ('a': word, other)
  where
    (word, other) = nextWord "n apple"
```

Which simplifies to

```
nextWord (' ':"apple") = ([], "apple")
```

Substituting back into our expression for `nextWord "n apple"`, we get

```
nextWord ('n':" apple") = ('n': word, other)
  where (word, other) = ([], "apple")
```

which simplifies to

```
nextWord ('n':" apple") = ('n':[], "apple")
```

or

```
nextWord ('n':" apple") = ("n", "apple")
```

Now substituting that back into our expression for `nextWord "an apple"`, we get

```
nextWord ('a':"n apple") = ('a': word, other)
  where (word, other) = ("n", "apple")
```

which simplifies to

```
nextWord ('a':"n apple") = ('a':"n", "apple")
```

or

```
nextWord ('a':"n apple") = ("an", "apple")
```